# Make clickable click here to edit application details in web form

Tags: excel, vba

I try Following code

Souce code for the link
Click here to edit Application Details

```
Set AllHyperlink = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
    
        For Each Hyperlink In AllHyperlink
            If Hyperlink.innerText = "Click here to edit Application Details" Then
            Hyperlink.Click
        Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Souce code for the link
Click here to edit Application Details

I am trying to click  one hyperlink  for that i  try to write  vba code but not works any one help me out from this situation ...

Comment: in place of innerText use the: textContent 
'Even instead of clicking you can do:
 ΙΕ.Navigate Hyperlink.href